# Reset data Meteor method

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-accounts

I'm writing a reset data method for my Meteor app, to erase the database, create a user, generate some fake data for this user etc. I'm declaring a server side method using the xolvio:cleaner and the accounts package to do this:

```
import {Accounts} from 'meteor/accounts-base';
import {resetDatabase} from 'meteor/xolvio:cleaner';

Meteor.methods({
// ..
'resetData':()=> {    
        resetDatabase(null, ()=>{

            Accounts.onCreateUser((options, user) => console.log(user));

            Accounts.createUser({
                username: 'bob',
                email: 'bob@kaya.com',
                password: 'rastamanvibration',
                profile: {
                    first_name: 'Bob',
                    last_name: 'Marley'
                }
            });    
        });
    }
});
```

This seems very straight forward to me yet I'm getting the following error:

```
    Exception while invoking method 'resetData' Error: insert requires an argument
W20170622-23:28:16.817(-7)? (STDERR)     at [object Object].insert (packages/mongo/collection.js:468:11)
W20170622-23:28:16.819(-7)? (STDERR)     at [object Object]._.each.Mongo.Collection.(anonymous function) [as insert] (packages/aldeed_collection2-core.js:232:19)
W20170622-23:28:16.820(-7)? (STDERR)     at AccountsServer.meteorInstall.node_modules.meteor.accounts-base.accounts_server.js.Ap.insertUserDoc (packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:1328:25)
W20170622-23:28:16.821(-7)? (STDERR)     at meteorInstall.node_modules.meteor.accounts-password.password_server.js.createUser (packages/accounts-password/password_server.js:1050:25)
W20170622-23:28:16.822(-7)? (STDERR)     at AccountsServer.meteorInstall.node_modules.meteor.accounts-password.password_server.js.Accounts.createUser (packages/accounts-password/password_server.js:1119:10)
W20170622-23:28:16.823(-7)? 
...
```

Comment: have you tied a simple schema to Meteor users? Also, this package states that it will work only in ```debugOnly``` enveronment

Comment: I've not created a simple schema for Meteor users, it doesn't look like I need to. Also this is happening while running meteor debug...

Comment: The error is actually not returning the user on the Accounts.onCreatedUser callback! woopsie

Answer (score 1):

This error happens when user is not returned to the onCreateUser method:

```
Accounts.onCreateUser((user)=> {
  // do things
  return user;
})
```